# Wpf slider center tick value

Tags: wpf, slider

I have a slider which has a min value of -127 and a max value of 127. On startup the slider is positioned in the middle, so at value 0.
Is it possible to have the text 0 to be shown at the tick, so you can visibly see where the center is?

```
<Slider Margin="3"
            Minimum="-127"
            Maximum="127"
            TickPlacement="BottomRight"
            TickFrequency="2"
            IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
            SmallChange="1" />
```

Here is a picture of my slider.

[image: slider with ticks, shown 0 value on center ticks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got what I wanted. I used a DockPanel under the Slider to layout the TextBlocks.
One for the center 0, one on the right side to set the max value and another one on the left side to set the min value.

I couldn't find any other solution that did what I wanted. If there is, post it here :)

XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Slider x:Name="SpeedSlider"
                    Margin="3"
                    Foreground="DarkGray"
                    Value="{Binding SliderValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Maximum="{Binding Steps,
                                                    Mode=TwoWay,
                                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Minimum="{Binding MinSteps,
                                                    Mode=TwoWay,
                                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    SmallChange="2"
                    TickFrequency="4"
                    TickPlacement="BottomRight"
                    ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=SpeedSlider,Path=Value}">
    </Slider>
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                         Text="{Binding MinSteps,
                                                    Mode=TwoWay,
                                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         Width="100"
                         Background="Transparent"
                         IsReadOnly="True"
                         BorderThickness="0" />
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                         Text="{Binding Steps,
                                                    Mode=TwoWay,
                                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         Width="100"
                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                         Background="Transparent"
                         IsReadOnly="True"
                         BorderThickness="0" />
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                             Text="0"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Image:

[image: slider with text]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way with the slider alone, I'd try:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Slider Grid.Row="2" Margin="3" Width="150"
        Minimum="-127"
        Maximum="127"
        TickPlacement="BottomRight"
        TickFrequency="2"
        IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
        SmallChange="1" />
    <TextBlock Text="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,-5,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

EDIT: I just realized you are not new to this, so you must have thought of this trivial solution ...